# Using curl to upload link

Tags: php, curl

I need your help because i don't know where is problem of this simple code.

original code is work but on the second code, it's dont work.

```
<?php
    $fast = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.server.org/api/get-server'));

    if($fast->error !== 'success') die('Error!');
    $url = file_get_contents('http://image.com/logo.png');
    $tmpfile = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");
    $filearray = array('files[]'=>'@'.$tmpfile);
    $handle = fopen($tmpfile, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $url);
    fclose($handle);
    $file = array('files[]'=>'@'.$tmpfile);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fast->server);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $filearray);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $return = json_decode($result, true);
    print_r($return);
    echo $return[0]['url'] . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

it's work perfectly, but i need just post a url with a parameter on this website.

here is a example of request:

```
Post:server.com/api/remote-upload?link=my_url_link
```

so i have modified this code like this for don't open file on my server:

```
    <form method="post" action=""> 
        Url : <input type="text" name="link" size="12"><br> 
              <input type="submit" value="OK"> 
    </form>

<?php
    $my_link = $_POST['link']; 
    $fast = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.server.org/api/get-server'));

    if($fast->error !== 'success') die('Error!');
    $filearray = array('link'=>$my_link); //param

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fast->server);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $filearray);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $return = json_decode($result, true);
    print_r($return);
?>
```

nothing was returned.. and the result is Array()

i have test variable but i don't know why is don't work?

Comment: You have HTML and PHP code intermingled. Wrap your PHP code in PHP tags. `<?php ... ?>`.

Comment: thanks for reply @bloodyKnuckles, but on postman app i don't need to download file then i send on api url. it's very fast, if i need to open a big file on my server just for upload on api url, it's bad way :(

Comment: You're doing `?link` but using a POST array `$_POST['link']` that should be `$_GET['link']` and a GET method in your form. `method="get"`. If not, then use  `$_REQUEST['link']`

Comment: Plus, if you're using your entire code in the same file, you need to use `isset()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, api need a POST request i have tested with $_REQUEST['link'] but same result

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i don't have any error, it's just $return variable was empty

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my code.

here is simple code but it's work perfectly for big file or anything format:

```
$links = $_REQUEST['link']; //value of param
$api = "http://www.server.org/api/remote-upload"; //api server 

    $post = array('link' => $links);//param ?link=link you want to upload

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$api);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $result;
```